# Hashed format in windows 7 or above

Tags: windows, hash, kerberos, ntlm, salt

I need to find some materials about how Security Accounts Manager(SAM) works in windows 7+. I am confused with the storage format of hashed value.

Many materials (such as, [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager)) tells me that it uses NTLM(or NTLM v2). However, as far as I understand, the security level of NTLM is very low. Most OS(such as unix) will provide random `salt` to enhance basic security level. For NTML, we can break it easily with `brute force` in several days(even several hours with great device). Also, if we use `rainbow table`, we can achieve perfect result.

Some other materials (such as, [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM)) tells me that Windows Vista or above has replaced NTLM with Kerberos. Does it affect SAM? If so, in default, which hash algorithm does it use in Windows 7 or above?

To make my question clearly, I want to list them below.

1. Does NTLM or NTLMv2 use salt?
2. Which algorithm does windows 7 or windows 8 use for SAM?
3. Whether kerberos affects the hashed format of SAM?

Answer (score 1):

1) Algorithms for LM, NTLM and NTLMv2 Session Security you can find at: http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html.

2) Which protocol is chosen depends on configuration (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738867%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Very often it's set to the highest level: Send NTLMv2 response only\refuse LM & NTLM.

3) No. There's no correlation or dependence between LM/NTLM/NTLMv2 Session Security and Kerberos. They're completely different protocols, independent from each other.